# Django: default user model RunTimeWarning about naïve DateTimeField

Tags: python, django

All my models except my User model inherit from this model:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Whenever a user signs-up, I get the following warning:

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField User.date_joined received a naive datetime (2018-07-04 06:38:11.288567) while time zone support is active.

Since I don't control the user creation process (I'm using the default user model supplied by Django), I can't figure out how to solve this.

Comment: Seems you are changed the *default user registration* behavior. Can you show the sign-up code and User model, if extended from Abstract User class ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge I haven't. there's no sign-up code or user model in my code because it's all utilized with a library called `django-registartion` that simply includes templates.

Answer (score 0):

Use `timezone` of django utils.

```
from django.utils import timezone

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField()

    # override default save funtion 
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.modified_date = timezone.now()
        return super(BaseModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks, but my user model doesn't inherit from BaseModel so this doesn't apply. I don't have access to the class, hence the question.

Comment: I see. Is there any particular reason why you can't access the class? If you mean the default user class, you can try creating a custom user class to manipulate default behavior.

Comment: yeah but that seems like a wild overkill. I mean, especially if Django is complaining about two native features (one being timezone, the other being the default user class)

Comment: True, I got into django recently, so I'm not sure how to deal with it. `timezone.now()` fixed the issue that I was facing.
If you made changes to default timezone in `settings.py` maybe changing it back to default can help.

Comment: I would, but I changed the timezone in order to be able to use it ;)